# viewing small pictures as the big picture?

Tags: javascript, web, web-deployment

I don't really know what the problem is here.
I am trying to view the small pics as big pics when I click on them. I have succeeded, however, an error message is appearing in the inspector-window that says: "Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined"

here is the code to make the small images big.

```
var Bigimg = document.getElementById("BigImg");
var smallimg = document.getElementsByClassName("small-img"); // this is an array

smallimg[0].onclick=function() {
    Bigimg.src = smallimg[0].src;
}

smallimg[1].onclick=function() {
    Bigimg.src = smallimg[1].src;
}

smallimg[2].onclick=function() {
    Bigimg.src = smallimg[2].src;
}

smallimg[3].onclick=function() {
    Bigimg.src = smallimg[3].src;
}
```

again it's working as it should, however, I am trying to move on to the next step where I am trying to get my shop-cart to function, but I am trying to test my code with the help of Console.log(the button I am pressing) and it's not working.

Comment: I am leaning towards one of your `smallimg` elements not existing. If there are only 3 elements with the class name "small-img" then referring to `smallimg[3]` then you would get the undefined error.

Comment: no there are 4 elements, so 4 smaller pictures. And one more weird thing, when I open "inspect" from the html file which name is "product-detail.html" which is where these pictures are located, I do not get the error. its only when I inspect the "shoppingcart.html"

Comment: I just learned another way to program it, the problem is solved. here is the code for those who read this: 
    var Bigimg = document.getElementById("BigImg");
    var smallimg = document.getElementsByClassName("small-img");

    for (var i=0; i<smallimg.length;++i){
        var smallPic = smallimg[i];
        smallPic.addEventListener("click", function(event){
            var picClicked = event.target;
            Bigimg.src = picClicked.src;
        })
    }